# How can I save a variable as a bytestring?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Ik this is a dumb question, but if I have this:

```
a :: B.ByteString
a = "a"
```

I get an error that says "Couldn't match type B.ByteString with type [Char]". I know what's the problem but I don't know how to fix it, could you help? thx.

Comment: Hello there. I'm not sure which `ByteString` you're using exactly, but if you dig around in [the haddock](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.3.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html) you might find interesting functions like `pack` and `unpack`. Perhaps one of these might help you convert a `[Char]` (otherwise aliased as a `String`) to a `ByteString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Character string literals in Haskell, by default, are always treated as `String`, which is equivalent to `[Char]`. Most string-like data structures define a function called `pack` to convert from, and the `bytestring` package is [no exception](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.3.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:pack) (Note that this is `pack` from `Data.ByteString.Char8`; the one in `Data.ByteString` converts from `[Word8]`).

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8(pack)

a :: B.ByteString
a = pack "a"
```

However, GHC also supports an extension called [`OverloadedStrings`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/overloaded_strings.html). If you're willing to enable this, `ByteString` implements a typeclass called [`IsString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString). With this extension enabled, the type of a string literal like `"a"` is no longer `[Char]` and is instead `forall a. IsString a => a` (similar to how the type of numerical literals like `3` is `forall a. Num a => a`). This will happily specialize to `ByteString` if the type is in scope.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

a :: B.ByteString
a = "a"
```

If you go this route, make sure you understand [the proviso](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.11.3.1/docs/Data-ByteString.html#t:ByteString) listed in the docs for this instance. For ASCII characters, it won't pose a problem, but if your string has Unicode characters *outside* the ASCII range, you need to be aware of it.